# create a 3-column carousel slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel

I want to create a 3 column carousel slider. I want the images to the left and right appear 50%(see image). Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Can you provide us your code?

Comment: I use the slider from the link:    
https://github.com/michaelsoriano/content-slider
in order to make some changes.
I also found slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)  but it doen't work..

Comment: I found this bootstrap slider http://jsbin.com/jadahetoxi/3/edit?html,css,js
I want the active item (centered image) to have other cursor type.
I tried the following:

.carousel-inner > .item.active{ cursor:crosshair !important; }

but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this css style: `.carousel-inner:hover {
cursor: crosshair;
}`

Comment: I tried that and It doesn't work..

Comment: can you pls create a working fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aris2134/cg1qk1ne/#&togetherjs=wILbz8kJFQ

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Check it out :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me ask you one more question.
I want left and right image to be black and white  except from centered image. I have to use the following css3:
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
Where should I write it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing your question or create another one so that answers will fit to your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue and tried this:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,              <<-- this
        margin: 24,
        nav: false,
        dots: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        stagePadding: 100,       <<-- this   
        autoWidth:true,          <<-- this
        center: true,            <<-- this
})
```

- `loop`: so that you have left & right neighbours
- `stagePadding`: Padding left and right on stage (can see neighbours).
- `autoWidth`: for customizeable item width
- `center`: for your active will be on the center

for stagePadding, you can adjust your desired size.
source:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html